# Publish SWF with project settings

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs6

I've created a Flash Professional (CS6) project, and the project settings show 2 src paths:

- ./
- ./src

However the ActionScript settings dialog doesn't share the same settings. This means if I try to publish or debug from the main CS6 window (or FlashBuilder), it will fail because it doesn't have the correct sources.

**How can I get the project settings to update the main FLA settings?** I mean, surely this should be automatic, otherwise I'd have to input the same details twice.

Please see the 2 images below to explain better:

[image: Project Settings][image: ActionScript Settings]

Answer (score 0):

try adding all folders from **Project properties source** tab to the **Advanced ActionScript 3.0 settings Source path** tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I knew that already, but I thought it should do it automatically. It already knows my source folders, so surely it should add them

Comment: You need to modify your project file with script. But to create script you will need more time than doing it manually a hundred times (since it takes seconds to manually add it). So my advice is to do it manually.